# Sparse matrix, left matrix divide in C++

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I have two sparse matrices A and B and I want to compute X as `X = A\B` also the same solution to the equation `A*X = B`
Is there a library in C++ that has this functionality?, I tried Eigen with SparseLU solver but it's taking too much time, when dealing with very large sparse matrices ((6*6)millions), much longer than Matlab.
any ideas?
Edit: 
Here's the solving snippet in Eigen and OpenCV, the matrix is originally an image, the output is also an image, also it's better if B or EIN in the snippet to be dense but I can't do so in Eigen

```html
Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>> Solver;
EA.makeCompressed();
Solver.compute(EA);
if (Solver.info() != Eigen::Success) std::cout << Solver.lastErrorMessage() << std::endl;
else std::cout << "Success !" << std::endl;
cv::SparseMat IN(MatTraverse(Image));
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> EIN = SparseCV2Eigen(IN);
Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> OUT = Solver.solve(EIN);
Eigen::MatrixXf OUTM(OUT);
OUTM.resize(Image.cols,Image.rows);
cv::Mat CVOUT(OUTM.rows(), OUTM.cols(), CV_32F, OUTM.data());
```

Another, the same equation can be solved in Matlab using `X = A\B` in a much faster time

Comment: These kind of questions are explicitly _off-topic_ here. Read point #4 from this [help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] along with your compiler flags?

Comment: Show what you tried and may be someone can help you make it work

Comment: Make sure you compiled with compiler optimization ON. Also, is the matrix symmetric?

Comment: The first question you should ask is if you explicitly need to know `A\B`. Even if `A` and `B` are sparse, this will often be a (big) dense matrix. Often it is sufficient just to multiply by `B` and 'solve' with `A` on-the-fly.

Comment: @ggael I did so with the rest of the optimization steps illustrated in the Eigen documentation but with no noticeable improvement, no it is not a symmetric matrix

Comment: , @chtz I don't get it, how multiplying Ax = B by B on both sides will solve for x ??

Comment: @Avi Ginsburg  I edited the question, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: @AbdarhmanTaha: I meant if you want to multiply something with `X`, e.g., ` X*y` you instead can calculate: `luA.solve(B*y)` (assuming `luA` is an LU-decomposition of `A`.

Comment: @AbdarhmanTaha: sorry I did not paid attention that B was a sparse matrix too. The slow computation now makes sense.

Comment: @chtz the time taken for decomposition is too long, that's the main problem, time

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:
http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#operators

It has lots operators for matrix:

operators:  +  −  *  /  %  ==  !=  <=  >=  <  >
Overloaded operators for Mat, Col, Row and Cube classes

Meanings:

- Addition of two objects
  −
  Subtraction of one object from another or negation of an object

/
Element-wise division of an object by another object or a scalar
*
Matrix multiplication of two objects; not applicable to the Cube class unless multiplying a cube by a scalar

%
Schur product: element-wise multiplication of two objects

==
Element-wise equality evaluation of two objects; generates a matrix of type umat with entries that indicate whether at a given position the two elements from the two objects are equal (1) or not equal (0)
!=
Element-wise non-equality evaluation of two objects

> =
>   As for ==, but the check is for "greater than or equal to"
>   <=
>   As for ==, but the check is for "less than or equal to"
>
> As for ==, but the check is for "greater than"
>   <
>   As for ==, but the check is for "less than"

Comment: The question was not about element-wise operations at all. If arma provides sparse-solvers (with sparse right-hand-side), the answer may be relevant.